# Filter output of running command

Tags: bash, text-processing

I am running a program that prints output in 4 different forms defined by the first word of the command `INFO :` , `SEVERE :` , `WARNING :`  & `ERROR :`  and the text following it.

- I want the command to only print info and error and nothing else.
- Also, I want to do it live while it is printing commands.

Please tell if any such way exists.

Comment: Just to make it clear: You want to start filtering the output of the command _after_ starting it and while it's outputting data to standard output, connected to a terminal (not to a file)?

Comment: Welcome to the site. When asking questions about text processing, please be sure to add a minimal reproducible example of the problem - i.e. (possible anonymized) example input, desired output, what you already tried, and in which way the output you got from your attempts deviates from the expectation. That way you can avoid receiving answers that you already know won't work, and contributors can verify proposed solutions before posting them as answers. One relevant aspect is knowing whether all output you want to print is _on the same line_ as the keyword, or if it spreads across lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use grep for this

```
yourcommand.sh | grep -e "INFO :" -e "ERROR :"
```